# How do I determine if an XmlNode has a specific attribute?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I would like to place an if condition within the sub that will tell it to run when the xml node STORE with attribute TEST="test.doc" does not exist. Any suggestions would be great. I'm new to vb.

```
Sub InsertNode(ByVal doc As XmlDocument)   
    Dim City As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement

    Dim Location As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("store")
    Location.SetAttribute("test", "test.doc")

    Dim books As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("books")
    books.InnerXml = "New Words"
    Location.AppendChild(books)

    City.AppendChild(store)
End Sub 'InsertNode
```

---

Sample of the XML file

```
<city>
    <store test="test.doc">
        <books>
        "New Words" 
        </books>
    </store>
</city>
```

Comment: When "what" xml attribute doesn't exist?  City?  That's an element, which is a different thing.

Comment: sorry, i had the attribute in <> so it was blocked.

Comment: Probably oughta post a little XML to see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
If Not doc.SelectSingleNode("//store[@test='test.doc']") Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! Your statment really helped me out.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that *Location* is the node you want to check to see if your attribute exists:

```
If Location.Attributes.ItemOf("test") Is Nothing Then
    'Attribute doesnt exist
Else
    'Attribute does exist
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** My post attempts to answer the original question asked by @Judy. It does not directly address the highly modified version of the question (and the title) that exists at present.

---

You can check if an element "Store" exists in the following way :

```
Dim storeNode as XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Store")
If storeNode isnot Nothing Then
  'The "Store" node was found.
Else
  'The "Store" node was not found.
End If
```

Consequently, you can check if the attribute test exists in the StoreNode in the following way:

```
Dim testAttribute as XmlAttribute = CType(storeNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Test"),  XmlAttribute)

If testAttribute isnot nothing then
  'The "Test" attribute was found.
Else
  'The "Test" attribute was found.
End If
```

And finally, you can check if the "Test" attribute contains the value "test.doc" in the following way:

```
If testAttribute.Value = "test.doc" Then
  'The value matches.
End If
```

I'm sure you can now combine these three checks into a single block. My purpose in this obviously verbose explanation is to clarify the concept.